# Changing default "Play" image

Tags: flash, flowplayer

I am trying to change the default "Play" image in FlowPlayer which comes up when the player loads and is ready to play the clip.

Any clues or resources?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way would be to find the image in the source, I think it is in a .fla used as a library the last time I looked, replace it and recompile flowplayer.core yourself.  This page describes how to get your development environment configured: http://flowplayer.org/documentation/developer/development-environment.html

Another way would be to hide the `play` plugin and replace it with your own.  So something like this with `onFinish`, you'll need to find all the other callbacks you need as well, like load or start, pause, etc.

```
onFinish: function(){ this.getPlugin("play").hide(); }
```